# Range of elliptic operator in sobolev space $W^{1,2}$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, elliptic-operators

my book claims that the weak elliptic operator $A:W^{1,2}(\Omega) \to W^{1,2}(\Omega)^\prime$ where, $\Omega$ is an open bounded region for example,
$A(u)(v)=\int_\Omega \sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij} \ \partial_i v \ \partial_ju \ dx$ and $a_{ij}$ are symmetric functions in $L^\infty$, has the range $R(A)=\{ F \in W^{1,2}(\Omega)^\prime ; F(1)=0\}$. This is used to show that this operator has closed range with codimension 1, and thus is a fredholm operator, because the nullspace are the constant functions. 
That constant functions are mapped to zero is obvious, but i cant see why the converse is also true. Could someone help me out?

Comment: I don't know what your definition of weakly elliptic operators is, but this should follow from some version of Poincaré's inequality.